# parse file name and include inplaced mk files using GNU make

Tags: parsing, gnu-make

Suppose there is a directory `/opt/dvp/gmake/`, and in this directory there are three files: `a.mk`, `a-b.mk` and `a-b-c.mk`.

Just to clarify, in `a-b-c.mk` there are definitions and configurations to a specific program, library, etc., which I generic call artifact. In `a-b.mk` there are difinitions to all artifacts in `a-b` group, and in `a.mk` there are definitions to all artifacts in `a` group.

I want to write a makefile where I call `make ARTIFACT=/opt/dvp/gmake/a-b-c.mk`, and in the makefile to automatically `-include /opt/dvp/gmake/a-b-c.mk`, `-include /opt/dvp/gmake/a-b.mk` and `-include /opt/dvp/gmake/a.mk`.

I looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348903/recreate-directory-structure-and-recursively-process-each-file-with-gnu-make), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993726/copy-files-recursively-with-gnu-make), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60951344/gnu-make-recursive-directory-listing), at the GNU Make [documentantion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions), tried many forms of `foreach` in combination with `call` and `shell` functions, but I was not able to do it.

TIA

Comment: Do you still need a solution to this?

Comment: Thanks, but not anymore. I suppose I can click on `Delete` on my question, right?

Comment: As it does not add information, I think yes. If you are still working with GNUmake, you may look at https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt for supporting functions in programming. Analyzing a string like `a-b-c` can be done with `glob-match` for example.

Comment: I will take a look at `gmtt`. I will delete this question in a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really getting how exactly the programs etc get hold of the "specifics" in the .mk-files. Perhaps adding a sample of the rules to the question would help.

One way might be to use `.` as separator instead of `-`, and remove suffixes one by one using `basename`:

```
# $ make foo.bar.baz
# foo.bar.baz
# foo.bar
# foo
%:
    @echo $@
    @echo $(basename $@)
    @echo $(basename $(basename $@))
```

In the case of your files (other naming schemes can make it prettier):

```
-include $(ARTIFACT)

# remove .mk, then .c, then append .mk
-include $(basename $(basename $(ARTIFACT))).mk

# remove .mk, then .c, then .b, then append .mk
-include $(basename $(basename $(basename $(ARTIFACT)))).mk
```